# Windows 7 doesn't Sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Troubleshooting a Windows 7 PC that wouldn’t sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/221042/troubleshooting-a-windows-7-pc-that-wouldnt-sleep)

I recently started facing problem with the Sleep feature of Windows 7. Whenever I press the sleep button, it goes into sleep mode but soon after a second, it automatically turns on and shows the Login window.

Could someone point me what's happening in there?

Answer (score 1):

Run `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` to see which devices can wake up the PC again. Now disable the ability to wake up.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of your USB devices is randomly turning it on. Follow the first answer from the link provided by goblinbox. That explains how to fix the issue.