# Troubleshooting procedure to identify a rogue process

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, rogue

I have a laptop with Windows 10 installed. I usually put the computer to sleep rather than switching it off.

I have noticed that the laptop may wake up from its sleep and stay awake, so that the battery is drained when I wake up in the morning.

I would like to prevent my laptop to wake up from its sleep. How would I troubleshoot and identify processes that wake it up?

I have followed [this procedure](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-stop-windows-10-randomly-waking-from-sleep/) but without success. For all intents and purposes, lid open/closed does not change anything.

Thank you very much.

Comment: run [powercfg -devicequery wake_armed](https://superuser.com/a/519529/174557) to see which device wakes up the device

Comment: magical. I will until tomorrow to check if what you said is true to confirm. So far, it is true. Apparently, I had forgotten to disable wake from sleep in one power mode. This is fixed. I ran your command and I received "Mouse" as an output. I unplugged the mouse and ran the command again and received a "None" output. So it looks like the problem is solved.
You can post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 EDIT: still not solved. Maybe it is a software issue? How would I go about identifying which process is responsible for waking up the computer?

Comment: look in eventlog why Windows was resumed.